# Long formatting yields awful table

Tags: formatting, longtable

I just tried to format my longtable but the end of the table leaves to much space between the last and the second last column. Since someone helped me to format the table I do not know how to change it, so that it fits for 8 columns instead of nine. Can someone help me to adjust the table so that each column is equally wide?

Here is my Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

%some important packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    %set font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             %set input encoding
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}         %language settings
\usepackage{graphicx}                       %package to include graphics
\usepackage{lscape}                         %package to rotate pages
\usepackage{booktabs}                       %nice rules in tables

%packages for LaTeX that provides various features to facilitate writing math   
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amstext}   
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\parskip1ex % sets paragraph without indent but small space between paragraphs

\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}

    % tables and stuff                  
\usepackage{array,longtable,siunitx} % for extending array and tabular environments/nice longtables [siuntix for S[table-format] etc]
\usepackage[skip=1.ex]{caption} %defines space between caption and table (among other things)                           
\usepackage{tabularx}                       %package for column width and linebreaks in table cells
\usepackage{textcomp}                       %package support of the text companion fonts
\usepackage{exscale}                        %package for nice summation sign 

\usepackage{hhline}                         % for double lines
\usepackage{natbib}                         %package for bibliography
\usepackage{ragged2e}                       %package provides less extreme raggedness than the standard LaTeX commands \flushleft and \flushright
\usepackage{multirow}                       %package to combine cells in tables
\usepackage{eurosym}                        %package to get eurosymbol per \euro
\usepackage{verbatim}                       % package for verbatim evironment
\usepackage{float}                          %package to define position of tables and figures
\usepackage[small]{titlesec} % for smaller titles
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for references
\usepackage{paralist} % for compactitem and compactenum
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} % for appendices

%adjustment of page parameters
\usepackage{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.3}     % set line spacing to 1.3pt    

% page and text block parameters
\setlength{\textheight}{22.86cm}        
\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}            
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1cm}         
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1cm}        
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.76cm}         

%space between footnote and text
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10.0pt}            


%title
\title{{\large title{blabla}}\\
\vspace{3mm}{\normalsize Bachelor Thesis}
}

%author
\author{Moritz Name\footnote{blabla}\\}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
    \begin{spacing}{.85}
        \begin{longtable}{@{} l
                S[table-format= 1.2]
                S[table-format= 1.2]
                S[table-format= 1.3]
                S[table-format= -2.1] |
                S[table-format= -1.2]
                S[table-format= 1.2]
                S[table-format= 1.3] 
                @{}}    
            \caption{Augmented Gravity Estimation - (Common Native Language (cnl))} \label{table:cnlessex} \\
            \toprule
            Country & {$\widehat{\textit{ex}}_j$} & {SEs} & {p-Val} & {\%-Effect} & {$\hat{S}_i$} & {SEs} & {p-Val}  \\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead

            \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{(Table \ref{table:cnlessex}, continued)}\\ 
            \addlinespace
            \toprule
            Country & {$\widehat{\textit{ex}}_j$} & {SEs} & {p-Val} & {\%-Effect} & {$\hat{S}_i$} & {SEs} & {p-Val}  \\
            \midrule
            \endhead

            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on following page)}\\
            \endfoot
            \bottomrule
            \endlastfoot
            %insert results
            USA & 5.15 & 0.23 & 0.000 & -60.8 & 0.59 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\                       
            ARG & 1.17 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -19.2 & 0.91 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            AUS & 2.42 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -35.6 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.781 \\                       
            AUT & 1.54 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -24.4 & 0.61 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            BEL & 5.18 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -61.0 & -1.62 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\                      
            BEN & -3.60 & 0.40 & 0.000 & 92.5 & -0.39 & 0.22 & 0.076 \\                      
            BGD & -0.22 & 0.27 & 0.424 & 4.0 & 0.38 & 0.20 & 0.058 \\                        
            BOL & -2.84 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 67.6 & -0.05 & 0.20 & 0.803 \\                      
            BRA & 2.33 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -34.5 & 1.13 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            CAF & -3.77 & 0.52 & 0.000 & 98.4 & 0.24 & 0.23 & 0.297 \\                       
            CAN & 3.23 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -44.4 & 0.11 & 0.17 & 0.518 \\                       
            CHE & 2.45 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -35.9 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\                       
            CHL & 1.98 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -30.2 & -0.21 & 0.18 & 0.243 \\                      
            CHN & 4.57 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -56.5 & 0.53 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\                       
            CMR & -1.40 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 28.9 & -0.59 & 0.19 & 0.002 \\                      
            COL & -1.02 & 0.26 & 0.000 & 20.4 & 0.84 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            CRI & -1.62 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 34.2 & 0.25 & 0.19 & 0.188 \\                       
            DNK & 2.04 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -31.0 & 0.50 & 0.17 & 0.003 \\                       
            DOM & -2.11 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 46.9 & -0.23 & 0.20 & 0.250 \\                      
            ECU & -1.71 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 36.4 & 0.28 & 0.19 & 0.141 \\                       
            EGY & -2.70 & 0.27 & 0.000 & 63.2 & 1.07 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\                       
            ESP & 2.15 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -32.4 & 0.79 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            FIN & 1.09 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -17.9 & 1.19 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            FRA & 3.78 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.7 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\                       
            GBR & 4.12 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -52.7 & 0.08 & 0.17 & 0.638 \\                       
            GHA & -0.37 & 0.31 & 0.232 & 7.0 & -1.64 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\                       
            GRC & -0.52 & 0.24 & 0.031 & 9.9 & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                        
            GTM & -2.63 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 61.3 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.752 \\                       
            HND & -3.70 & 0.32 & 0.000 & 95.8 & -0.17 & 0.20 & 0.395 \\                      
            IND & 2.02 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -30.7 & 1.05 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            IRL & 2.50 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -36.5 & -0.38 & 0.17 & 0.025 \\                      
            IRN & -2.17 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 48.5 & 1.03 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\                       
            ISR & 2.03 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -30.9 & -0.17 & 0.20 & 0.395 \\                      
            ITA & 3.79 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.8 & 0.60 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\                       
            JAM & -2.15 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 47.8 & -0.49 & 0.19 & 0.010 \\                      
            JOR & -2.18 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 48.7 & -0.11 & 0.21 & 0.600 \\                      
            JPN & 4.38 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -54.9 & 1.37 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            KEN & -0.72 & 0.27 & 0.008 & 14.0 & -0.82 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\                      
            KOR & 3.74 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.3 & 0.87 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            LKA & 1.14 & 0.29 & 0.000 & -18.7 & -1.63 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\                      
            MEX & 1.04 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -17.2 & 0.95 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            MLI & -4.76 & 0.36 & 0.000 & 137.8 & -0.05 & 0.23 & 0.828 \\                     
            MOZ & -0.79 & 0.35 & 0.024 & 15.4 & -2.46 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\                      
            MUS & -0.19 & 0.28 & 0.498 & 3.5 & -1.14 & 0.20 & 0.000 \\                       
            MWI & -2.95 & 0.34 & 0.000 & 71.0 & -0.83 & 0.23 & 0.000 \\                      
            MYS & 4.34 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -54.6 & -0.44 & 0.17 & 0.010 \\                      
            NER & -1.57 & 0.38 & 0.000 & 33.1 & -3.06 & 0.24 & 0.000 \\                      
            NIC & -4.10 & 0.33 & 0.000 & 110.8 & 0.28 & 0.20 & 0.162 \\                      
            NLD & 4.61 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -56.8 & -0.97 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                      
            NOR & 0.60 & 0.25 & 0.017 & -10.3 & 0.73 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            NPL & -3.53 & 0.33 & 0.000 & 90.0 & 0.47 & 0.23 & 0.041 \\                       
            NZL & 2.28 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -34.0 & -0.15 & 0.19 & 0.430 \\                      
            PAK & 1.83 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -28.4 & -0.26 & 0.19 & 0.171 \\                      
            PAN & -0.36 & 0.29 & 0.211 & 6.8 & -1.55 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\                       
            PER & 0.23 & 0.27 & 0.395 & -4.1 & 0.11 & 0.19 & 0.563 \\                        
            PHL & 1.13 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -18.5 & -0.23 & 0.18 & 0.201 \\                      
            PNG & -0.65 & 0.37 & 0.079 & 12.5 & -1.52 & 0.24 & 0.000 \\                      
            PRT & 0.48 & 0.24 & 0.045 & -8.4 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\                        
            PRY & -2.33 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 52.9 & 0.14 & 0.20 & 0.484 \\                       
            RWA & -5.70 & 0.41 & 0.000 & 181.8 & 0.12 & 0.24 & 0.617 \\                      
            SEN & -2.28 & 0.32 & 0.000 & 51.4 & -0.50 & 0.21 & 0.017 \\                      
            SLV & -3.18 & 0.31 & 0.000 & 78.3 & -0.37 & 0.20 & 0.064 \\                      
            SWE & 2.11 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -31.9 & 0.86 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            SYR & -5.53 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 173.1 & 1.65 & 0.21 & 0.000 \\                      
            TGO & -4.04 & 0.36 & 0.000 & 108.3 & -0.61 & 0.23 & 0.008 \\                     
            THA & 2.75 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -39.3 & 0.03 & 0.18 & 0.868 \\                       
            TUN & -2.18 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 48.7 & 1.17 & 0.20 & 0.000 \\                       
            TUR & 0.03 & 0.25 & 0.902 & -0.6 & 1.05 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                        
            UGA & -3.28 & 0.35 & 0.000 & 81.5 & -0.39 & 0.23 & 0.090 \\                      
            URY & -0.55 & 0.28 & 0.052 & 10.4 & -0.05 & 0.20 & 0.803 \\                      
            VEN & -0.80 & 0.28 & 0.004 & 15.7 & 0.05 & 0.19 & 0.792 \\                       
            ZAF & 2.20 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -32.9 & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.681 \\                       
            ZMB & -0.68 & 0.33 & 0.039 & 13.2 & -1.18 & 0.23 & 0.000 \\                      
            ZWE & -1.55 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 32.5 & -0.07 & 0.19 & 0.713 \\  

                        \bottomrule[1.5pt] 
                        \multicolumn{8}{p{0.88\linewidth}}{\scriptsize\textbf{Notes}:  A list of all 74 countries and their ISO-Codes can be found in the Appendix. The regression is ran with Ordinary Least Squares. No constant was included. The columns SEs and p-Val denote Standard Errors and p-Values respectively. The column "\%-Effect" indicates the percentage deviation in trade costs from he average country. For an parameter $\hat{b}$ it is computed as $100*(e^{-\theta\hat{b}}-1)$.}                               
                    \end{longtable}
                \end{spacing}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You just need to allow space for the `-` sign, and make your note narrower.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

%some important packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    %set font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}             %set input encoding
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}         %language settings
\usepackage{graphicx}                       %package to include graphics
\usepackage{lscape}                         %package to rotate pages
\usepackage{booktabs}                       %nice rules in tables

%packages for LaTeX that provides various features to facilitate writing math   
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amstext}   
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\parskip1ex % sets paragraph without indent but small space between paragraphs

\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}

    % tables and stuff                  
\usepackage{array,longtable,siunitx} % for extending array and tabular environments/nice longtables [siuntix for S[table-format] etc]
\usepackage[skip=1.ex]{caption} %defines space between caption and table (among other things)                           
\usepackage{tabularx}                       %package for column width and linebreaks in table cells
\usepackage{textcomp}                       %package support of the text companion fonts
\usepackage{exscale}                        %package for nice summation sign 

\usepackage{hhline}                         % for double lines
\usepackage{natbib}                         %package for bibliography
\usepackage{ragged2e}                       %package provides less extreme raggedness than the standard LaTeX commands \flushleft and \flushright
\usepackage{multirow}                       %package to combine cells in tables
\usepackage{eurosym}                        %package to get eurosymbol per \euro
\usepackage{verbatim}                       % package for verbatim evironment
\usepackage{float}                          %package to define position of tables and figures
\usepackage[small]{titlesec} % for smaller titles
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for references
\usepackage{paralist} % for compactitem and compactenum
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} % for appendices

%adjustment of page parameters
\usepackage{setspace} 
\setstretch{1.3}     % set line spacing to 1.3pt    

% page and text block parameters
\setlength{\textheight}{22.86cm}        
\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}            
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1cm}         
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1cm}        
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.76cm}         

%space between footnote and text
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10.0pt}            


%title
\title{{\large title{blabla}}\\
\vspace{3mm}{\normalsize Bachelor Thesis}
}

%author
\author{Moritz Name\footnote{blabla}\\}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
    \begin{spacing}{.85}
        \begin{longtable}{@{} l
                S[table-format= -1.2]
                S[table-format= 1.2]
                S[table-format= 1.3]
                S[table-format= -2.1] |
                S[table-format= -1.2]
                S[table-format= 1.2]
                S[table-format= 1.3] 
                @{}}    
           \caption{Augmented Gravity Estimation - (Common Native Language (cnl))} \label{table:cnlessex} \\
            \toprule
            Country & {$\widehat{\textit{ex}}_j$} & {SEs} & {p-Val} & {\%-Effect} & {$\hat{S}_i$} & {SEs} & {p-Val}  \\
            \midrule
            \endfirsthead

            \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{(Table \ref{table:cnlessex}, continued)}\\ 
            \addlinespace
            \toprule
            Country & {$\widehat{\textit{ex}}_j$} & {SEs} & {p-Val} & {\%-Effect} & {$\hat{S}_i$} & {SEs} & {p-Val}  \\
            \midrule
            \endhead

            \bottomrule
            \addlinespace
            \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on following page)}\\
            \endfoot
            \bottomrule
            \endlastfoot
            %insert results
            USA & 5.15 & 0.23 & 0.000 & -60.8 & 0.59 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\                       
            ARG & 1.17 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -19.2 & 0.91 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            AUS & 2.42 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -35.6 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.781 \\                       
            AUT & 1.54 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -24.4 & 0.61 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            BEL & 5.18 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -61.0 & -1.62 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\                      
            BEN & -3.60 & 0.40 & 0.000 & 92.5 & -0.39 & 0.22 & 0.076 \\                      
            BGD & -0.22 & 0.27 & 0.424 & 4.0 & 0.38 & 0.20 & 0.058 \\                        
            BOL & -2.84 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 67.6 & -0.05 & 0.20 & 0.803 \\                      
            BRA & 2.33 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -34.5 & 1.13 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            CAF & -3.77 & 0.52 & 0.000 & 98.4 & 0.24 & 0.23 & 0.297 \\                       
            CAN & 3.23 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -44.4 & 0.11 & 0.17 & 0.518 \\                       
            CHE & 2.45 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -35.9 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\                       
            CHL & 1.98 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -30.2 & -0.21 & 0.18 & 0.243 \\                      
            CHN & 4.57 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -56.5 & 0.53 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\                       
            CMR & -1.40 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 28.9 & -0.59 & 0.19 & 0.002 \\                      
            COL & -1.02 & 0.26 & 0.000 & 20.4 & 0.84 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            CRI & -1.62 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 34.2 & 0.25 & 0.19 & 0.188 \\                       
            DNK & 2.04 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -31.0 & 0.50 & 0.17 & 0.003 \\                       
            DOM & -2.11 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 46.9 & -0.23 & 0.20 & 0.250 \\                      
            ECU & -1.71 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 36.4 & 0.28 & 0.19 & 0.141 \\                       
            EGY & -2.70 & 0.27 & 0.000 & 63.2 & 1.07 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\                       
            ESP & 2.15 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -32.4 & 0.79 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            FIN & 1.09 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -17.9 & 1.19 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            FRA & 3.78 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.7 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\                       
            GBR & 4.12 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -52.7 & 0.08 & 0.17 & 0.638 \\                       
            GHA & -0.37 & 0.31 & 0.232 & 7.0 & -1.64 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\                       
            GRC & -0.52 & 0.24 & 0.031 & 9.9 & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                        
            GTM & -2.63 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 61.3 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.752 \\                       
            HND & -3.70 & 0.32 & 0.000 & 95.8 & -0.17 & 0.20 & 0.395 \\                      
            IND & 2.02 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -30.7 & 1.05 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            IRL & 2.50 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -36.5 & -0.38 & 0.17 & 0.025 \\                      
            IRN & -2.17 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 48.5 & 1.03 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\                       
            ISR & 2.03 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -30.9 & -0.17 & 0.20 & 0.395 \\                      
            ITA & 3.79 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.8 & 0.60 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\                       
            JAM & -2.15 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 47.8 & -0.49 & 0.19 & 0.010 \\                      
            JOR & -2.18 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 48.7 & -0.11 & 0.21 & 0.600 \\                      
            JPN & 4.38 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -54.9 & 1.37 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            KEN & -0.72 & 0.27 & 0.008 & 14.0 & -0.82 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\                      
            KOR & 3.74 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.3 & 0.87 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            LKA & 1.14 & 0.29 & 0.000 & -18.7 & -1.63 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\                      
            MEX & 1.04 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -17.2 & 0.95 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            MLI & -4.76 & 0.36 & 0.000 & 137.8 & -0.05 & 0.23 & 0.828 \\                     
            MOZ & -0.79 & 0.35 & 0.024 & 15.4 & -2.46 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\                      
            MUS & -0.19 & 0.28 & 0.498 & 3.5 & -1.14 & 0.20 & 0.000 \\                       
            MWI & -2.95 & 0.34 & 0.000 & 71.0 & -0.83 & 0.23 & 0.000 \\                      
            MYS & 4.34 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -54.6 & -0.44 & 0.17 & 0.010 \\                      
            NER & -1.57 & 0.38 & 0.000 & 33.1 & -3.06 & 0.24 & 0.000 \\                      
            NIC & -4.10 & 0.33 & 0.000 & 110.8 & 0.28 & 0.20 & 0.162 \\                      
            NLD & 4.61 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -56.8 & -0.97 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                      
            NOR & 0.60 & 0.25 & 0.017 & -10.3 & 0.73 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                       
            NPL & -3.53 & 0.33 & 0.000 & 90.0 & 0.47 & 0.23 & 0.041 \\                       
            NZL & 2.28 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -34.0 & -0.15 & 0.19 & 0.430 \\                      
            PAK & 1.83 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -28.4 & -0.26 & 0.19 & 0.171 \\                      
            PAN & -0.36 & 0.29 & 0.211 & 6.8 & -1.55 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\                       
            PER & 0.23 & 0.27 & 0.395 & -4.1 & 0.11 & 0.19 & 0.563 \\                        
            PHL & 1.13 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -18.5 & -0.23 & 0.18 & 0.201 \\                      
            PNG & -0.65 & 0.37 & 0.079 & 12.5 & -1.52 & 0.24 & 0.000 \\                      
            PRT & 0.48 & 0.24 & 0.045 & -8.4 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\                        
            PRY & -2.33 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 52.9 & 0.14 & 0.20 & 0.484 \\                       
            RWA & -5.70 & 0.41 & 0.000 & 181.8 & 0.12 & 0.24 & 0.617 \\                      
            SEN & -2.28 & 0.32 & 0.000 & 51.4 & -0.50 & 0.21 & 0.017 \\                      
            SLV & -3.18 & 0.31 & 0.000 & 78.3 & -0.37 & 0.20 & 0.064 \\                      
            SWE & 2.11 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -31.9 & 0.86 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\                       
            SYR & -5.53 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 173.1 & 1.65 & 0.21 & 0.000 \\                      
            TGO & -4.04 & 0.36 & 0.000 & 108.3 & -0.61 & 0.23 & 0.008 \\                     
            THA & 2.75 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -39.3 & 0.03 & 0.18 & 0.868 \\                       
            TUN & -2.18 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 48.7 & 1.17 & 0.20 & 0.000 \\                       
            TUR & 0.03 & 0.25 & 0.902 & -0.6 & 1.05 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\                        
            UGA & -3.28 & 0.35 & 0.000 & 81.5 & -0.39 & 0.23 & 0.090 \\                      
            URY & -0.55 & 0.28 & 0.052 & 10.4 & -0.05 & 0.20 & 0.803 \\                      
            VEN & -0.80 & 0.28 & 0.004 & 15.7 & 0.05 & 0.19 & 0.792 \\                       
            ZAF & 2.20 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -32.9 & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.681 \\                       
            ZMB & -0.68 & 0.33 & 0.039 & 13.2 & -1.18 & 0.23 & 0.000 \\                      
            ZWE & -1.55 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 32.5 & -0.07 & 0.19 & 0.713 \\  

                        \bottomrule[1.5pt] 
                        \multicolumn{8}{p{0.7\linewidth}}{\scriptsize\textbf{Notes}:  A list of all 74 countries and their ISO-Codes can be found in the Appendix. The regression is ran with Ordinary Least Squares. No constant was included. The columns SEs and p-Val denote Standard Errors and p-Values respectively. The column "\%-Effect" indicates the percentage deviation in trade costs from he average country. For an parameter $\hat{b}$ it is computed as $100*(e^{-\theta\hat{b}}-1)$.}                               
                    \end{longtable}
                \end{spacing}}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem disappeared  when I commented the table note at the end. I suspect the width alloted (0.88 \textwidth) was a bit too large.

I propose an automatic computation of this width, thanks to the `threeparttablex` package, which measures the width of the table. You have to use the `ThreePartTable` environment, and define the table notes  beginning with the `TableNotes` environment, then the content of the table, and finally an `\inserTableNotes` command, where you want to have them.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
%some important packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %set font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %set input encoding
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel} %language settings
\usepackage{graphicx} %package to include graphics
\usepackage{lscape} %package to rotate pages
\usepackage{booktabs} %nice rules in tables

%packages for LaTeX that provides various features to facilitate writing math
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\parskip1ex % sets paragraph without indent but small space between paragraphs

\usepackage{abstract}
\renewcommand{\absnamepos}{flushleft}
\setlength{\absleftindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\absrightindent}{0pt}

% tables and stuff
\usepackage{array,longtable,siunitx} % for extending array and tabular environments/nice longtables [siuntix for S[table-format] etc]
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage[skip=1.ex]{caption} %defines space between caption and table (among other things)
\usepackage{tabularx} %package for column width and linebreaks in table cells
\usepackage{textcomp} %package support of the text companion fonts
\usepackage{exscale} %package for nice summation sign

\usepackage{hhline} % for double lines
\usepackage{natbib} %package for bibliography
\usepackage{ragged2e} %package provides less extreme raggedness than the standard LaTeX commands \flushleft and \flushright
\usepackage{multirow} %package to combine cells in tables
\usepackage{eurosym} %package to get eurosymbol per \euro
\usepackage{verbatim} % package for verbatim evironment
\usepackage{float} %package to define position of tables and figures
\usepackage[small]{titlesec} % for smaller titles
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
\usepackage{hyperref} % for references
\usepackage{paralist} % for compactitem and compactenum
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix} % for appendices

%adjustment of page parameters
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.3} % set line spacing to 1.3pt

% page and text block parameters
\setlength{\textheight}{22.86cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.76cm}

%space between footnote and text
\setlength{\footnotesep}{10.0pt}


%title
\title{{\large title{blabla}}\\
\vspace{3mm}{\normalsize Bachelor Thesis}
}

%author
\author{Moritz Name\footnote{blabla}\\}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
  \begin{spacing}{.85}
    \begin{ThreePartTable}
      \setTableNoteFont{\scriptsize}
      \begin{TableNotes}[flushleft]
        \item[] \textbf{Notes}: A list of all 74 countries and their ISO-Codes can be found in the Appendix. The regression is ran with Ordinary Least Squares. No constant was included. The columns SEs and p-Val denote Standard Errors and p-Values respectively. The column `\%-Effect’ indicates the percentage deviation in trade costs from he average country. For a parameter $\hat{b}$ it is computed as $100*(e^{-\theta\hat{b}}-1)$.
      \end{TableNotes}
      \begin{longtable}{@{} l
          S[table-format= 1.2]
          S[table-format= 1.2]
          S[table-format= 1.3]
          S[table-format= -2.1] |
          S[table-format= -1.2]
          S[table-format= 1.2]
          S[table-format= 1.3]
          @{}}
          \caption{Augmented Gravity Estimation - (Common Native Language (cnl))} \label{table:cnlessex} \\
          \toprule
          Country & {$\widehat{\textit{ex}}_j$} & {SEs} & {p-Val} & {\%-Effect} & {$\hat{S}_i$} & {SEs} & {p-Val} \\
          \midrule
          \endfirsthead
          \multicolumn{8}{@{}l}{(Table \ref{table:cnlessex}, continued)}\\
          \addlinespace
          \toprule
          Country & {$\widehat{\textit{ex}}_j$} & {SEs} & {p-Val} & {\%-Effect} & {$\hat{S}_i$} & {SEs} & {p-Val} \\
          \midrule
          \endhead
          \bottomrule
          \addlinespace
          \multicolumn{8}{r@{}}{(continued on following page)}\\
          \endfoot
          % \bottomrule
          \endlastfoot
          %insert results
          USA & 5.15 & 0.23 & 0.000 & -60.8 & 0.59 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\
          ARG & 1.17 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -19.2 & 0.91 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\
          AUS & 2.42 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -35.6 & 0.05 & 0.18 & 0.781 \\
          AUT & 1.54 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -24.4 & 0.61 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\
          BEL & 5.18 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -61.0 & -1.62 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\
          BEN & -3.60 & 0.40 & 0.000 & 92.5 & -0.39 & 0.22 & 0.076 \\
          BGD & -0.22 & 0.27 & 0.424 & 4.0 & 0.38 & 0.20 & 0.058 \\
          BOL & -2.84 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 67.6 & -0.05 & 0.20 & 0.803 \\
          BRA & 2.33 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -34.5 & 1.13 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\
          CAF & -3.77 & 0.52 & 0.000 & 98.4 & 0.24 & 0.23 & 0.297 \\
          CAN & 3.23 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -44.4 & 0.11 & 0.17 & 0.518 \\
          CHE & 2.45 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -35.9 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\
          CHL & 1.98 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -30.2 & -0.21 & 0.18 & 0.243 \\
          CHN & 4.57 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -56.5 & 0.53 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\
          CMR & -1.40 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 28.9 & -0.59 & 0.19 & 0.002 \\
          COL & -1.02 & 0.26 & 0.000 & 20.4 & 0.84 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\
          CRI & -1.62 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 34.2 & 0.25 & 0.19 & 0.188 \\
          DNK & 2.04 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -31.0 & 0.50 & 0.17 & 0.003 \\
          DOM & -2.11 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 46.9 & -0.23 & 0.20 & 0.250 \\
          ECU & -1.71 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 36.4 & 0.28 & 0.19 & 0.141 \\
          EGY & -2.70 & 0.27 & 0.000 & 63.2 & 1.07 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\
          ESP & 2.15 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -32.4 & 0.79 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\
          FIN & 1.09 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -17.9 & 1.19 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\
          FRA & 3.78 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.7 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\
          GBR & 4.12 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -52.7 & 0.08 & 0.17 & 0.638 \\
          GHA & -0.37 & 0.31 & 0.232 & 7.0 & -1.64 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\
          GRC & -0.52 & 0.24 & 0.031 & 9.9 & 0.60 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\
          GTM & -2.63 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 61.3 & 0.06 & 0.19 & 0.752 \\
          HND & -3.70 & 0.32 & 0.000 & 95.8 & -0.17 & 0.20 & 0.395 \\
          IND & 2.02 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -30.7 & 1.05 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\
          IRL & 2.50 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -36.5 & -0.38 & 0.17 & 0.025 \\
          IRN & -2.17 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 48.5 & 1.03 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\
          ISR & 2.03 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -30.9 & -0.17 & 0.20 & 0.395 \\
          ITA & 3.79 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.8 & 0.60 & 0.16 & 0.000 \\
          JAM & -2.15 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 47.8 & -0.49 & 0.19 & 0.010 \\
          JOR & -2.18 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 48.7 & -0.11 & 0.21 & 0.600 \\
          JPN & 4.38 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -54.9 & 1.37 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\
          KEN & -0.72 & 0.27 & 0.008 & 14.0 & -0.82 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\
          KOR & 3.74 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -49.3 & 0.87 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\
          LKA & 1.14 & 0.29 & 0.000 & -18.7 & -1.63 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\
          MEX & 1.04 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -17.2 & 0.95 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\
          MLI & -4.76 & 0.36 & 0.000 & 137.8 & -0.05 & 0.23 & 0.828 \\
          MOZ & -0.79 & 0.35 & 0.024 & 15.4 & -2.46 & 0.22 & 0.000 \\
          MUS & -0.19 & 0.28 & 0.498 & 3.5 & -1.14 & 0.20 & 0.000 \\
          MWI & -2.95 & 0.34 & 0.000 & 71.0 & -0.83 & 0.23 & 0.000 \\
          MYS & 4.34 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -54.6 & -0.44 & 0.17 & 0.010 \\
          NER & -1.57 & 0.38 & 0.000 & 33.1 & -3.06 & 0.24 & 0.000 \\
          NIC & -4.10 & 0.33 & 0.000 & 110.8 & 0.28 & 0.20 & 0.162 \\
          NLD & 4.61 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -56.8 & -0.97 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\
          NOR & 0.60 & 0.25 & 0.017 & -10.3 & 0.73 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\
          NPL & -3.53 & 0.33 & 0.000 & 90.0 & 0.47 & 0.23 & 0.041 \\
          NZL & 2.28 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -34.0 & -0.15 & 0.19 & 0.430 \\
          PAK & 1.83 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -28.4 & -0.26 & 0.19 & 0.171 \\
          PAN & -0.36 & 0.29 & 0.211 & 6.8 & -1.55 & 0.19 & 0.000 \\
          PER & 0.23 & 0.27 & 0.395 & -4.1 & 0.11 & 0.19 & 0.563 \\
          PHL & 1.13 & 0.25 & 0.000 & -18.5 & -0.23 & 0.18 & 0.201 \\
          PNG & -0.65 & 0.37 & 0.079 & 12.5 & -1.52 & 0.24 & 0.000 \\
          PRT & 0.48 & 0.24 & 0.045 & -8.4 & 0.52 & 0.17 & 0.002 \\
          PRY & -2.33 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 52.9 & 0.14 & 0.20 & 0.484 \\
          RWA & -5.70 & 0.41 & 0.000 & 181.8 & 0.12 & 0.24 & 0.617 \\
          SEN & -2.28 & 0.32 & 0.000 & 51.4 & -0.50 & 0.21 & 0.017 \\
          SLV & -3.18 & 0.31 & 0.000 & 78.3 & -0.37 & 0.20 & 0.064 \\
          SWE & 2.11 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -31.9 & 0.86 & 0.17 & 0.000 \\
          SYR & -5.53 & 0.30 & 0.000 & 173.1 & 1.65 & 0.21 & 0.000 \\
          TGO & -4.04 & 0.36 & 0.000 & 108.3 & -0.61 & 0.23 & 0.008 \\
          THA & 2.75 & 0.26 & 0.000 & -39.3 & 0.03 & 0.18 & 0.868 \\
          TUN & -2.18 & 0.29 & 0.000 & 48.7 & 1.17 & 0.20 & 0.000 \\
          TUR & 0.03 & 0.25 & 0.902 & -0.6 & 1.05 & 0.18 & 0.000 \\
          UGA & -3.28 & 0.35 & 0.000 & 81.5 & -0.39 & 0.23 & 0.090 \\
          URY & -0.55 & 0.28 & 0.052 & 10.4 & -0.05 & 0.20 & 0.803 \\
          VEN & -0.80 & 0.28 & 0.004 & 15.7 & 0.05 & 0.19 & 0.792 \\
          ZAF & 2.20 & 0.24 & 0.000 & -32.9 & 0.07 & 0.17 & 0.681 \\
          ZMB & -0.68 & 0.33 & 0.039 & 13.2 & -1.18 & 0.23 & 0.000 \\
          ZWE & -1.55 & 0.28 & 0.000 & 32.5 & -0.07 & 0.19 & 0.713 \\
          \bottomrule[1.5pt]
          \addlinespace
          \insertTableNotes
        \end{longtable}
      \end{ThreePartTable}
    \end{spacing}}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]